# Sort array of objects on toggle, toggle not working

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to sort an array of objects by 'title' property. How can I switch sorting by Asc and Desc by a button toggle?

I have the below, but the data doesn't sort by toggle

```
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [toggleFilter, setToggleFilter] = useState(false);

  const sortedArray = useMemo(
    () =>
      toggleFilter
        ? [...data].sort((a, b) => a.title - b.title)
        : [...data].sort((a, b) => b.title - a.title),
    [data, toggleFilter],
  );

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        style={styles.flatlist}
        data={sortedArray}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.title}</Text>}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
      <View style={styles.container}>
    
        <Pressable
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => setToggleFilter(!toggleFilter)}
          testID="sort-direction">
          <Text style={styles.text}>{toggleFilter ? '⬇️' : '⬆️'}</Text>
        </Pressable>

      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: since your useMemo anyways depends on data and toggleFilter, why not put the logic inside a useEffect and then add toggleFilter in the dependencies. Would be a much more readable code.

Comment: I'm guessing your `title` is a string? If so, you want `a.title.localeCompare(b.title)` for a lexicographic sort.

Comment: @abhishekti7 _"why not put the logic inside a useEffect"_ - because this logic isn't a side-effect, it's just a new variable derived from another state. Putting this inside of a `useEffect` would require a new state value to store the sorted array (computed within the `useEffect`), which would trigger another rerender unnecessarily. Avoiding an effect for this sort of thing is also [called out in the docs](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#caching-expensive-calculations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to this!!

So the problem is with the sort in this scenario.

In the below code I am using only one sort and also String prototype "[localCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)"

NOTE: same can be achieved with "sort" function but "localCompare" suits well for your problem statement

```
const [data, setData] = useState([{ title: 'A' }, { title: 'B' }, { title: 'C' }, { title: 'D' }, { title: 'E' }]);
const [toggleFilter, setToggleFilter] = useState(false);

const sortedArray = useMemo(
    () => data.sort((a, b) => (toggleFilter ? b.title.localeCompare(a.title) : a.title.localeCompare(b.title))),
    [data, toggleFilter]
);

return (
    <View>
        <FlatList
            style={styles.flatlist}
            data={sortedArray}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.title}</Text>}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        />

        <Pressable style={styles.button} onPress={() => setToggleFilter(!toggleFilter)}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{toggleFilter ? '⬇️' : '⬆️'}</Text>
        </Pressable>
    </View>
);
```